# Generating random transition probability matrix python

Tags: python, matrix

I was wondering whether there is an easy way to generate a square matrix filled with random numbers in python, given some conditions:

- the rows have to sum up to 1.
- the values on the diagonal should be significantly higher than the
  other values.

This is a stochastic matrix, and generating one is possible, however the tricky part is the condition about the diagonal. 
e.g. for a 4x4 matrix the output should look something like this:

```
[[0.90, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04],
[0.01, 0.98, 0.005, 0.005],
[0.04, 0.01, 0.92, 0.03],
[0.00, 0.02, 0.03, 0.95]]
```

Are there good ways to generate such matrix for a variable size?

Comment: How significantly higher? Do you have a probability distribution to quantify that?

Comment: If all the values on the diagonal would be higher than 0.90, I would be happy! No probability distribution for quantifying yet.

Comment: Weeell, you could do `random.uniform(0.9, 1.0)` for the diagonal value and then generate a list of 3 other numbers and simply normalise them so that they sum up to `1 - diagonal_value`. But I'm certain some statistician will point out how this method generates a biased sample of numbers, so you probably don't want to do it. By the way, if you're okay with using numpy, consider adding the tag.

Comment: @DutchJ I can't imagine a situation where I would want random numbers but not even care what the distribution is. Can you give more context for the problem?

Comment: @Reti43 the other way round may be ok. Generate all off-diagonal entries first using a distribution with an appropriately small mean and then fill in the diagonal

Comment: @Max  Right now, it is just for testing my code, but manually generating such matrices will become tiresome if the dimensions become too large. I don't care about the exact numbers, but rather the idea behind it. i.e. Modelling 'random'  behaviour of customers buying product A, product B, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick-and-dirty solution

```
import random

k = 4

result = [[random.uniform(0, 0.1 / k) for i in range(k)] for j in range(k)]
for j, r in enumerate(result):
    r[j] += 1 - sum(r)
```

You may want to consider using a different random distribution and also have a look at numpy.

Comment: Summing numbers from a uniform distribution will get you a mean of (low + high) / 2 = 0.05. This means your diagonals will be very close to 0.95. 
 Use `np.array(result).diagonal()` to see that. The bigger your matrix, the ore obvious this is.

Comment: @Reti43 You mean they are not very random? One may be tempted to assume that but the variance of the diagonal elements will still be (n-1) times the variance of the off-diagonal elements, so that looks pretty ok to me.

Comment: The diagonals are random, but not uniformly so. Remember, they are constraint by the sum of the other numbers, you don't have that degree of freedom. As for the distribution for the sum of n uniform numbers, you're looking at the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution). For the limit n -> infinity, it's a normal distribution. So it'd be like generating the diagonals from the distribution N(0.95, σ).

Comment: The point of my initial suggestion was for the diagonal to be uniformly selected number. And since the remaining numbers are only scaled down, they still retain their uniform distribution. This may look okay to me, but my intuition felt there's something fishy about it, which is why I kept it as a suggestion. Anyway, the OP has been satisfied with your solution.

Comment: @Reti43 Ah, I see. Btw. I think your gut feeling re fishiness is spot on. Because the scaling factor you must use depends on all numbers you have drawn for that row the resulting entries will not be independent and also not uniformly distributed. I'm not saying my approach is the correct model for OP's problem but it is mathematically more convenient mostly because it avoids those dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method with `numpy.identity`, starting with a *k x k* identity matrix, adding a drift term to it, and then normalizing.

```
import numpy as np

k = 4
result = np.identity(4)

# Add a random drift term.  We can guarantee that the diagonal terms
#     will be larger by specifying a `high` parameter that is < 1.
# How much larger depends on that term.  Here, it is 0.25.
result = result + np.random.uniform(low=0., high=.25, size=(k, k))

# Lastly, divide by row-wise sum to normalize to 1.
result = result / result.sum(axis=1, keepdims=1)

# Check
print(result)
print(result.sum(axis=1))

# [[ 0.80736896  0.00663004  0.06474194  0.12125906]
#  [ 0.03545472  0.79746194  0.10495657  0.06212678]
#  [ 0.08566011  0.02632533  0.79709851  0.09091605]
#  [ 0.07298408  0.05698381  0.1585878   0.71144431]]
#
# [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
```

The above condensed to two lines:

```
result = np.identity(k) + np.random.uniform(low=0., high=.25, size=(k, k))
result /= result.sum(axis=1, keepdims=1)
```

Specifying a larger `high` parameter will get you a smaller ratio of "diagonals to the rest":

```
result = np.identity(k) + np.random.uniform(low=0., high=.60, size=(k, k))
result /= result.sum(axis=1, keepdims=1)
print(result.round(2))
# [[ 0.53  0.02  0.25  0.2 ]
#  [ 0.05  0.58  0.19  0.18]
#  [ 0.02  0.04  0.72  0.22]
#  [ 0.07  0.23  0.08  0.62]]
```